# What drug could interfere with a chip hooked into your nervous system?

Tags: biology, biochemistry, brain

Say a character had a chip implanted within their brain (thank you to everyone who helped with that question) and wanted a drug to try and mess with the chip's ability to hook into their senses and nervous system, which of the drugs available today could do this? And what would the general effects be?

I should say that ideally they wouldn't want to be totally incapacitated but rather able to move and think at least a little clearly, although this isn't necessary.

Comment: How do you imagine it's hooked into the nervous system? Just by electricity, interacting with the synaps, directly hooked up to the cell bodies, changing and monitoring the Na and K channels....? It can matter a lot for which drug to use and the effectiveness.

Comment: I imagined it was hooked into the synaps, but I would be open for any different ways depending on how that would effect the solution for disabling it

Comment: Clarification. Do you want to completely disable the chip or alter its function without damaging it?

Comment: HyperNym either but ultimately I want them to try and get it to stop working

Comment: You could probably use a psychedelic like LSD or similar. It's possible that the chip simply wouldn't be able to "decode" or "unscramble" the thoughts or mental activity of someone who's tripping.

Comment: Anyone for inducing an allergy to the material the chip is made of? It would be risky, as the side-effects can be bad, but it would likely cause inflammation and possibly disable the device. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5336431/ The same ingredients used to trigger immune reactions to a vaccine can enhance an immune reaction to the foreign material. In science, they do this to push an animal to produce antibodies scientists want made. I could see a scenario where one person's chip spontaneously failed due to this, inspiring deliberate attempts.

Answer (score 1):

> How do drugs cause their effects on the brain and behavior? Lesson 1 introduced students to the idea that a specific brain region, the reward system (part of the limbic system), regulates feelings of pleasure and that this region is activated by drugs of abuse. But what do drugs actually do in that brain region? Drugs interfere with neurotransmission.  ([Source](https://science.education.nih.gov/supplements/webversions/BrainAddiction/guide/lesson3-1.html))

We use a lot of drugs to affect the brain. From Caffeine stimulate neruotransmission to alcohol to shut it down. There are so many drugs that have both beneficial and deleterious effects (mostly deleterious!) that I'm not even going to try to enumerate them here.

*Please note that I'm assuming you're looking for suspension-of-disbelief. If you're looking for a "this one would actually work!" answer you need to explain **exactly** how that chip's connected **and** where.*

From that source...

- Methamphetamine
- Nicotine
- THC/Marijuana
- LSD
- alcohol
- Cocaine/amphetamines

Keep in mind that *any* drug not specifically designed to improve brain function (which is REALLY RARE) will cause it to loose efficiency (or worse). Therefore...

- Every recreational drug you've ever heard of is fair game to answer your question.
- Many pain drugs could be believably used.

On the other hand...

- Drugs meant to help with Parkinson's, Alheimer's, etc, could also be believably used wherein the affect of disabling the chip is a side-effect of the positive effort to help the brain (after all, evolutionarily, the chip isn't supposed to be there).